# how to change the Icon on flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I need some help , I am trying to build a web app using flutter, all things are good, but the problem is when I want to change the Icon of the web , It doesn't change ,I do not why , I add flutter dependecies   flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1, I run pub get and all the steps need for setting ,but nothing change
here is my pubspec.yaml file

[image]

and here is the output, nothing change , can anyone help me please?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add your image in web/icons

Add this line in index.html

```
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons/favicon1.jpg" />
```

Comment: for newbies (like me): i believe the path is from root of your flutter project. eg. in my project, in root folder, i have a folder called 'assets' and inside of that a folder called 'icon' so setting custom icon in my index.html looks like:  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/appIcon1024.png"/>